# Use two twig extensions on the same variable

Tags: twig

I need to print the content of a blogPost (which contains HTML content) with twig, so I have use the `raw` extension.

I also have to replace a part of the content by another, but how can I use the `replace` extension if there already is the `raw` one?

I have tried:

```
{{ blogPost.getPost()| raw | replace('[[video]]': '(your video here)') }}

{{ {{blogPost.getPost()| raw}} | replace('[[video]]': '(your video here)') }}

{{ blogPost.getPost()| raw, replace('[[video]]': '(your video here)') }}
```

but none of them works.

Comment: what "non of them works" means?

Comment: Yup sorry: I have Symfony exceptions !
the first one: Arguments must be separated by a comma. Unexpected token "punctuation" of value ":" ("punctuation" expected with value ",") in JtvEntityBundle:Default:blogPost.html.twig at line 30
The second one: A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression enclosed in parentheses (unexpected token "punctuation" of value "{" in JtvEntityBundle:Default:blogPost.html.twig at line 30
The last one: Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "," ("end of print statement" expected) in JtvEntityBundle:Default:blogPost.html.twig at line 30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
replace('[[video]]': '(your video here)')
```

should be

```
replace({'[[video]]': '(your video here)'})
```

That's because you need to pass an array to replace function and not a scalar value

### Edit

Try with

```
{{ blogPost.getPost()|replace({'[[video]]': '(your video here)'})|raw }}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have replace it by `{{ blogPost.getPost()| raw | replace({'[[video]]': '(your video here)'}) }}` and I don't have exceptions anymore but the `raw` doesn't work anymore !

Comment: There is no error but the HTML tags are printed as text !